# RubyMotion Image from URL in Motion-Game

Tags: ruby, cocos2d-x, rubymotion, motion-game

I am using RubyMotion motion-game.  I am trying to create a sprite, or ui widget, or really almost any other class that has an image associated with it.  The trick is I want to create it from a URL, not a file.

Is there is an existing way to do this in motion-game?  How?
I see api methods like MG::Sprite.new and MG::Web.new but am unsure of how to take data from a url and display it as a sprite.

If it doesn't exist would the solution involve exposing cocos stuff in C++?  Any help or examples of something similar would be appreciated.